# Правильно ли говорить "разукрашивать"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Хотела бы спросить по поводу "разукрашивать". У нас так пишут и говорят учителя в русской школе. На мой взгляд безграмотно совсем. Раскрашивать - да, но не разукрашивать.

Comment: Правильно — **раскрашивать**, раскраска. http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x

Answer (score 1):

Насчёт корректности слова **разукрасить** можете не сомневаться: поиском по *книгам* на "*разукрасил*" находятся многие сотни случаев употребления. Слово есть даже в словарях церковно-славянского языка, не говоря об Ушаковском и более поздних словарях. (*Слова разрисовать и **разукрасить** употр. **с усилительным оттенком*** - см. Словарь синонимов русского языка в двух томах, Евгеньева, 1971)

Оба глагола имеют здесь приставку-*интенсификатор* **рас**/**раз**, но разные по смыслу основы (красить - украшать).

> красить/покрасить -> **рас**крашивать/**рас**красить (всё намеченное, причём
>   каждый элемент покрасить своим цветом)
>
> украшать/украсить -> **раз**украшивать (устар. разукраш*ать*)/**раз**украсить (украсить обильно,
>   интенсивно, разнообразно, методично, по всему пространству и  т. п.)

"Проблемное" слово широко употребляется и в ироническом смысле: "*кто это тебя так разукрасил?*" (мальчику, который появился в школе весь в ссадинах).

Из глаголов с другими значениями (аналогичное значение приставки):

описать -> **рас**писать (описать что-либо, кого-либо в привлекательных *подробностях*)

одеться -> **раз**одеться (одеться изысканно или пёстро, броско *во всех отношениях и мелочах*)

нарисовать (что-либо) -> **раз**рисовать (что-либо чем-либо, напр. покрыть рисунками *большое пространство*, напр. обои на всей стене)

Answer (score 0):

У этих слов попросту разных смысл. Да, у *"разукрасить"* есть пометка *разговорное,* но при этом оно широко используется в литературе и, конечно же, повседневной речи. Цитирую [отсюда](https://ask.fm/russian/answers/131690742844):

РАСКРАСИТЬ — расписать краской (красками), покрасить в разные цвета.

РАЗУКРАСИТЬ. Разг. 1. Украсить множеством чего-л. Р. новогоднюю ёлку. Р. город флагами. *Р. гриву лошади лентами. Р. участников концерта. Мороз разукрасил окна узорами.* / Шутл. Оставить на лице, теле следы от побоев. *Кто это тебя так разукрасил?*
2. Рассказывая, представить кого-, что-л. в более привлекательном, чем на самом деле, виде. *Р. факты до неузнаваемости. Р. рассказ подробностями.*

Мне нравится первый ответ на эту тему [здесь](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2170611-kak-pravilno-govorit-raskrasit-kartinku-ili-razukrasit-kartinku.html):

> Если посмотреть на смысл и значение этих глаголов в словарях русского языка, то можно понять, что применение того или другого зависит только от собственно задачи. Если подразумевается **нанесение тоновых цветов на чистые участки и сектора картинки,** чтобы в итоге получилась картинка цветная, то следует применять *"раскрасить".* Если задача состоит в том, чтобы предложенную картинку **украсить какими-либо дополнительными рисунками, узорами и т. д.,** то естественно правильным будет применение термина *"разукрасить"*.

Comment: Разве глагол может быть термином?

Comment: Это не ко мне вопрос. А вообще, почему бы и нет?

Comment: Не может, только существительные.

Comment: *Ещё как может.*

Comment: Слово, являющееся точным обозначением определённого **понятия**. Вы пропустили лишнюю букву С в вопросе.

Comment: @oleedd Глагол _может_ быть термином, напр. _"имплементировать" (юр.), "пассивировать" (техн.)и т. п._

Comment: @Alex_ander Термин - это понятие. Глагол - это не понятие. Если не согласны, то где указано, что термины - это не только существительные. И в словарях нет ничего в пользу других частей речи. Можно и прилагательное образовать от "имплементирование" (то же, что и реализация) — "имплементированный". Не все же сложные по звучанию/смыслу слова считать терминами.

Comment: По форме занесения в списки и словари терминов - да, это отглагольные существительные. Однако при непосредственном употреблении в тексте (в начальной форме глагола или - для других слов - наоборот, в приведённой к глаголу форме) такие слова разве перестают быть терминами?

Comment: @Alex_ander Перестают. Никогда такого не встречал. Термин - это научное слово. Учёные не называют так глаголы/прилагательные/наречия. "в приведённой к глаголу форме" — не понял. Без @ оповещение часто не приходит для чужих вопросов/ответов. (Не получил его.)

Comment: О простой логике, которой я в данном случае воспользовался, иногда спорят, но вот пример: https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/termin-opredelenie-ponyatiya-i-ego-suschnostnye-priznaki/viewer _(в полемике цитируется С.Д. Шелов: Тезис о том, что термин - это всегда либо существительное, либо субстантивное словосочетание, вряд ли может быть принят для установления языковой специфики термина.)_

Comment: @Alex_ander В научной литературе всё от третьего лица, а "мы считаем" - это уже субъективность. "*В роли термина может выступать всякое слово*" — предлоги, союзы, частицы? Абсурд. || Я же не против, если это будет общепринято - использоваться в учебных заведениях, в научных работах. Но этого нет. || Без @ оповещение о вашем комментарии не приходит!